# Joomla Installation: 'Database Type' not showing in drop down selection box

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, mysqli

I have been trying to figure out for three days why I cannot connect to my Database so I can install Joomla.

I have PHP Installed and in my '.ini' File:'php.ini-development' file I do have mysql and mysqli installed:

[image: php.ini-development]

I have my SQLServer and Database Connected I am using WorkBench to manage it FYI.

[image: MYSQLServer Managed through workbench]

Yet I keep getting this message and I don't have any Database Types in the selection box:

[image: Joomla Install Error and Database Type list Empty]

Yes, I have seen many forums on here and everywhere I have been researching it for three days now, although everything has not worked for me. So if you would please help me!

PS: I do have 'public $dbtype = 'mysql';' in my configuration file, so please don't say to do that because that was almost half of what the forums have said. I also have IIS7  installed and running for another website, I don't know if that could be the problem or not if it were interfering with SQL.

Comment: What u can try doing is taking the .sql file out of the installation folder and manually importing it to your database, manually add the main data to the co figuration.php, then deleting the installation folder. It might be possible that Joomla doesnt go well with Workbench but I will test that later

Comment: Which .sql file there are a few? I added the database setting into the configuration.php file. I then deleted the installation file in Joomla, then tried viewing it and it gave me an error saying there is not installation folder...

Answer (score 4):

In my case, below packages were missing:

```
 - libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
 - php5-mysql
```

I installed them by `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql` and restarted the `apache2` & `mysql` service.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was on the extension directory configuration, on php.ini. I discovered that, when joomla installation can't access the MySQL extension, or others database extensions, the database is not showed. My property extension_dir was set to the wrong directory, so the PHP wasn't able to load any extension, and of course, joomla installation wasn't able to show any database types to be choosen.

You can search for "extension_dir" property on php.ini file and check if its value is right.

Comment: Can you explain more of what "extension_dir" is and how we can know if "it's value is right"? This variable is supposed to point to the mysql install? Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

On my CentOS 7 there was "php-pgsql" missing (for PostgreSQL database). Installing it resolved the problem.

```
\# sudo yum install php-pgsql

\# sudo tail -1 /var/log/yum.log

Dec 21 19:33:35 Installed: php-pgsql-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, mysql, the package php-mysql is missed

using this command and then restart apache2

`sudo apt install  php-mysql`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by running php.exe and it shows me line where I had issue. It was missing ";" in front of one descriptive line. This fixed error.